# angular app with service-worker (pwa) is not working as expected

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-config, ngsw-config

Working on an offline angular with service workers get the reference from https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

Application working fine offline the only issue is with cache update mechanism if i use `"installMode": "prefetch"` application works fine offline but files in cache never update on updation of the files on server . If i use "installMode": "lazy"` app does not work offline.

below is the `ngsw-config.json`  of my application.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
          "/*.manifest",
           "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    } 
  ]
}
```

also tried `updateMode` but still cache files not update on changes

```
  "installMode": "prefetch",
  "updateMode": "prefetch",
```

Comment: just override angular's service  worker with my own service worker to make it work

Comment: You used your own sw instead of Angular's to solve this issue..? Have u tried my answer? Any issues with that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `lazy` for `index.html` and other small files usually is not needed as these files are very light weight. I would recommend to split assets and other heavy files to a separate group in service worker config file and use `lazy` only for them:

```
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "app2",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
           "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then look at the `dist` folder after you build your app. It will have a service worker configuration file created based on rules you wrote in `ngsw-config.json` (it will hold a list of all cached files with hash keys). Try to exclude that file from being cached, by adding explanation mark at the start:

```
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "!/some-file-not-to-cache.js"
        ]
      }
    },
```